# Firebase Invites for React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-invites

We are currently using Firestack on a React Native project which is great, however we also need the features available via Firebase's "Invites" capability.

Is anyone aware of a React Native module (eg on github) for Firebase Invites, iOS and Android ?

Or alternatively - is there another service/API that can provide similar app invite management for mobile (ideally w/ React Native support but we can always bridge if needed) ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase invites is based on Firebase dynamic links: [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/)

React-Native-Firebase is a great open source library to use Firebase with react native. [React-Native-Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

The library supports Dynamic Links so with a little work you can use it to enable the Firebase Invites feature.

[React-Native-Firebase (Dynamic Links)](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.*/links/reference/links)